# is passing activity to another object a good practice?

Tags: android

I have:

```
public MissionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   public SoundPlayer getSoundPlayer();
   public DiffrentSoundPlayer getDiffrentSoundPlayer()
   //...etc.
}
```

I am passing this Activity in constructor to another class that need all 
this soundplayers and assetManager. All these players need to be created in activity. My question is: is this a good practice in Android to pass reference to Activity to another object?

Comment: Your code example does not work?

Comment: I think if you consider passing an Activity with a load of soundplayers and stuff, you need to reconsider the architecture of your app. You don't want to pass more than strictly necessary, and you don't want to pass more than two or three parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the activity is not in itself problematic, but given the scope of activities is something that should be done thoughtfully.

Depending on your specific case I would consider wrapping the objects that you have created on the activity inside a data transfer object and pass that object to the class that needs the objects. And by "data transfer object" I simply mean an object whose sole purpose is to store the data/objects that you are transferring.

But simply passing the activity to the other class is also completely okay, as long as you don't store the activity in that other class (just store the objects that you need from the activity).